# Create a new div by inserting an embed javascript?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have html element like this:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

How I should write in embed.js to create a new div in t he div above, without using jquery ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the outcome you want would look like the following markup:

```
<div>This is the new div</div>
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

If that is the case, you will need to:

1. Find the script tag with a `src` equal to 'js/embed.js'
2. Select the parent (the `div` container)
3. Use `insertBefore()` to add a new `div`

If this all true, the code would look something like this:

```
var parent,
    i = 0,
    scripts = document.scripts,
    newDiv =document.createElement('div');

newDiv.innerHTML = "This is the new div";

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    if (scripts[i].getAttribute('src') === 'js/embed.js') {
        parent = scripts[i].parentNode;
        parent.parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, parent)
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/dUT3E/4/)

If you want your markup to be like this:

```
<div>
    <div>This is the new div</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

Then use this:

```
var i = 0,
    scripts = document.scripts,
    newDiv = document.createElement('div');

newDiv.innerHTML = "This is the new div";

for (i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    if (scripts[i].getAttribute('src') === 'js/embed.js') {
        scripts[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, scripts[i])
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/dUT3E/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `document.write()`:

```
document.write('<div></div>');
```

`document.write()` writes the output at the position where it is being executed, in your case within the first `<div>`.

Comment: Will not work with XHTML, but in general best solution for OP question.

Answer (score 1):

The following might work:

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>

function addDiv()
{
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<div>some other text</div>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector("div script[src='js/embed.js']").parentElement.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```